# Why a certain map between spheres is contracting?

Tags: geometry, lipschitz-functions, spheres, contraction-operator

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I am trying to understand a step in a proof of the following lemma (the proof is [here](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ6fur9JzTAhUJWhQKHeUxBYIQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.jyu.fi%2Fresearch%2Freports%2Frep100.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE54zII8UH70WIcqJiOOW78_fLPVw&sig2=u4i8NKtTFPxQu7mIyWo_vg), lemma 2.7, pg 6):

(This lemma provides a way of proving [Kirszbraun theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem)).

> Lemma: Let $\{x_1 , \dots, x_k \}$ be a finite collection of points in $\R^n$, and let $\{y_1 , \dots, y_k \}$ be a collection of points in $\R^m$ such that
>   $$|y_i − y_ j | ≤ |x_ i − x_ j | \, \text{ for all } \, i, j \in \{1, . . . , k\}.$$
>   If $r_ 1 , \dots , r_ k$ are positive numbers such that
>   $$ \cap_{i=1}^k \bar B(x_ i , r _i ) \neq \emptyset, $$
>   then
>   $$ \cap_{i=1}^k \bar B(y_ i , r _i ) \neq \emptyset .$$

*Here is what happens in the proof:*

Define $$G:\R^m \to \R, \,G(y)= \max_{i=1,\dots,k} \frac{|y − y _i |}{r _i}$$

$G: \R^m \to \R$ is a continuous function satisfying
$G(y) \to \infty$ as $|y| \to \infty$. Hence, $G$ achieves its minimum at a
point $w \in \R^ m$ , and we need to show that $G(w) \le 1$.

Assume by contradiction that $G(w) := \lambda >1$. Let $J$ denote
those indices $j \in \{1, . . . , k\}$ for which $|w − y _j | = r _j λ$. Pick a point $$x \in\cap_{j \in J} \bar B(x _j , r _j ) ,$$

and consider the following two sets:
$$D=\{ \frac{x _j − x}{|x _j − x|} |\, j \in J\} \subseteq \mathbb{S}^{n−1},$$
$$D'=\{ \frac{y _j − w}{|y _j − w|} |\, j \in J\} \subseteq \mathbb{S}^{m−1}.$$

The author than says it is easy to see that the natural map* $D \to D'$ strictly decreases the **Euclidean** distances.

Why is it so?

*The natural map means we keep the indices.

Comment: It's a standard proof ploy: you introduce a lot of baggage about the situation and while your audience is still reeling around trying to comprehend it, you claim that the actual thing to be proved, restated in terms of your new constructions, is obvious.

Comment: In some sens you are right. But really the point is to use the fact that the image of this map $D \to D'$ must lie in an open hemisphere, so this gives us a "prefered direction" to move the point $w$ to obtain a lower value of $G$, contradicting the minimality. Indeed, this is a highly non-trivial proof in my opinion.

Comment: I was speaking tongue-in-cheek, of course. The key factor here is that since the $y_i$ are closer together than the $x_i$, balls of the same radii around them should have larger overlap, not smaller. The point of all the "baggage" was to arrive at a $w$ that is as far inside that overlap as possible. Though I've not followed it through, I believe the trick is to show that if $D'$ didn't decrease the distance, then moving $w$ in some direction would decrease $G(w)$, contradicting that $w$ minimizes $G$.

Comment: Sigh - I really should read all of your comment before replying. Then I could avoid repeating what you already said.

Answer (score 0):

Problem : In $V:=\mathbb{R}^m$, $$1\leq i\leq m,\
p^i,\ q^i\in V,\ |p^ip^j|\geq |q^iq^j|
$$ Then
$$
\bigcap\ B_{R_i}(p^i)\ni w_0 \Rightarrow \bigcap\ B_{R_i}(q^i)\neq
\emptyset\ \ast
$$

Note : This is a special case of Breham : In the
above, there
is piecewise distance preserving $f$ s.t. $f(p^i)=q^i$ However, we do not use his proof.

Reference : Alexandrov meets Kirszbraun - S.
Alexander, V. Kapovitch, A. Petrunin. It treats the more general
case

Proof :

Notation : In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $$ w\preceq z \Leftrightarrow
w_i\leq z_i
$$

$\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}^m$ is a metric space with standard Euclidean
metric. Define
$$ {\bf f} :=(f^0,\cdots, f^k) : \mathcal{X}\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^{k+1} $$

Let $f^i(w)=\frac{1}{2}|w-p^i|^2$, which is convex

Define $$Q\subset V,\ {\rm SupSet}\ Q : =\bigg\{ z\in V\bigg| \exists w\in Q\
{\rm s.t.}\ z\succeq w \bigg\} $$

(1) ${\rm SupSet}\ {\bf f}\ (\mathcal{X})$ is convex

Proof : Convexity of $f^i$ implies that
 \begin{align*} {\bf f}
(tw+(1-t)z) &\preceq t {\bf f}  (w) + (1-t) {\bf f} (z)
\end{align*}

(2) If $g^i(w) :=\frac{1}{2} |w-q^i|^2$ we have a claim
 that $$ {\rm SupSet }\
{\bf g}(\mathcal{X})\ni {\bf f}(w_0) $$ where $w_0$ is the vector in
$\ast$

Proof : If not there is a supporting hyperplane
$$\sum_i\alpha_ix_i=c$$ to ${\rm SupSet}
\ {\bf g}(\mathcal{X})$ separating it from ${\bf
f}(w_0)$

Hence $$ \sum_i \alpha_i f^i(w_0) < c={\rm inf}\ \bigg\{
\sum_i\alpha_i g^i(w)|w\in \mathcal{X} \bigg\}\ \ast\ast
$$

Hence if $$ F:=\sum_i \alpha_i f^i,\ G:=
 \sum_i\alpha_i g^i $$ we have a claim that $$
 F(w_F)\geq G(w_G)$$ which contradicts to $\ast\ast$, where $w_F,\ w_G$ are minimum points respectively

**Proof of Claim** : If $${\rm Dir}\ p^i -w_F =\frac{p^i
-w_F}{|p^i -w_F |},$$ then
\begin{align*} 0 &=d_{w_F} F\ {\rm Dir}\ (p^i -w_F) \\&=
-\frac{1}{2|p^i -w_F|} \sum_j \alpha_j \ \{ |p^i-w_F|^2+ |p^j-w_F|^2
- |p^i-p^j |^2 \} \ ({\rm cf.\ Cosine\ Law}) \\&\\ 2 F(w_F)&= \sum_{i,j}
\alpha_i\alpha_j |p^i-p^j|^2 \end{align*}